# git config doesn't honour current working dir

Tags: git, shell

Its pretty weird: The following code in a [longer shell script](https://github.com/gabyx/githooks/blob/7617bab39407dddc9ccdf65acb6b008e5c4f0d7d/base-template.sh#L454) (`sh`):

```sh
SHARED_ROOT="~/.githooks/shared/shared_hooks_103" # This is a git repo!
cd "$SHARED_ROOT" && pwd && git config --show-origin --get remote.origin.url
```

prints

```sh
.../.githooks/shared/shared_hooks_103
file:/private/tmp/test103-clone/.git/config     /tmp/test103
```

Showing that git takes the wrong config file...??

explicitly telling `git config` which file to take with:

```sh
git config -f "$SHARED_REPO/.git/config" --show-origin
```

works correctly.

I am puzzled how the above shell syntax cannot work under what circumstances or if its a strange git bug?

Comment: I can get this if I've got `GIT_DIR` exported, overriding Git's repo searching, is that what's happening here?

Comment: I dont think so .  https://github.com/gabyx/githooks/blob/7617bab39407dddc9ccdf65acb6b008e5c4f0d7d/base-template.sh#L454

Comment: Solved: Thanks somehow GIT_DIR gets set. It gets set by git obviously by entering the post-checkout hook, hm... is that expected?

Comment: Yes, I think shells Git invokes have the environment set up to point at the particular repo Git's working on. If you want recursive Gits to work on different repos you have to set up (or clean) the environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for whatever reason, during `git` hooks git sometimes leaks some internal `GIT_*` environment variables.  these can negatively affect other `git` operations that occur during the hooks.

in [pre-commit](https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit) (a git hooks framework I maintain), I use the following code to avoid these environment variables (while still preserving some important ones)

[pre_commit/git.py@95afd64](https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit/blob/95afd642f52b4d2a12ad605683c8f752e63530d0/pre_commit/git.py#L21-L35):

```
def no_git_env(_env=None):
    # Too many bugs dealing with environment variables and GIT:
    # https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit/issues/300
    # In git 2.6.3 (maybe others), git exports GIT_WORK_TREE while running
    # pre-commit hooks
    # In git 1.9.1 (maybe others), git exports GIT_DIR and GIT_INDEX_FILE
    # while running pre-commit hooks in submodules.
    # GIT_DIR: Causes git clone to clone wrong thing
    # GIT_INDEX_FILE: Causes 'error invalid object ...' during commit
    _env = _env if _env is not None else os.environ
    return {
        k: v for k, v in _env.items()
        if not k.startswith('GIT_') or
        k in {'GIT_EXEC_PATH', 'GIT_SSH', 'GIT_SSH_COMMAND'}
    }
```

the few whitelisted env variables enable `git` to perform some operations:

- `GIT_EXEC_PATH`: allows `git` to find its executable helpers
- `GIT_SSH` / `GIT_SSH_COMMAND`: allows `git` to use the user's setting for special `ssh` cloning instructions
- (there's probably more, but nobody has reported bugs needed others yet!)

Comment: Thanks a lot for these insight!